# How can I check if a GPU is being used for compute or is free?

Tags: linux, gpu

I am trying to determine which GPUs are currently utilized for compute on a GPU server.
Better yet, I'd like to be able to answer whether a GPU is "free" for running a new job. Ideally it'd poll periodically and once I identify a free card, I'd run my own job on it.

Any ideas whether there's a readymade way to do this?

Parsing the nvidia-smi output is an option, but is there a preexisting command line argument that lists the running processes on each GPU?

Answer (score 0):

After some further googling, it seems it's possible to figure this out from the PIDs list of currently executing compute process:

`nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid --format=csv,noheader -i 0`

The above would query GPU #0.  Next step is to do this in a loop.  And the number of GPUs can be inferred from:

`nvidia-smi -L | wc -l`

So a bash loop over the results of the former to snoop for an unoccupied GPU?  Thoughts about this?  Is there a more direct way of figuring this out?